# Setup Elasticsearch and Kibana on local

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Hi I would like to know how to set ELK on local machine (local host) on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download & Install & run elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/windows.html
2. Download & Install & run kibana: https://www.elastic.co/de/downloads/kibana

If you install them with default settings it should just work.